# FactoryGirl different object with same value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have a `Transaction` model, which has 2 attributes `buyer`, `seller` both of type `User`.

I need to create a Factory that has the same buyer and seller.

I have tried this :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :transaction do
   [...]
   factory :same_user_transaction do
      user = create(:user)
      buyer = user
      seller = user
   end
 end
end
```

but that doesn't work.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :transaction do
   [...]
   factory :same_user_transaction do
      buyer  { create(:user) }
      seller { buyer }
   end
 end
end
```

If you have a user factory, other ways to do this could be:

```
factory :same_user_transaction do
  association :buyer, factory: :user
  seller { buyer }
end
```

Or even better, using aliases:

```
factory :user, aliases: [:buyer] do
  first_name    "John"
  last_name     "Doe"
  date_of_birth { 18.years.ago }
end

factory :same_user_transaction do
  buyer
  seller { buyer }
end
```

Here's reference: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#aliases